# Sneak peak all pink even with no texture

Tags: rendering

I'm a new Blender/Verge3D user. I have a simple project with 4 objects and no texture. When I try to "sneak peak", they turn all pink. I browsed for a bit, and all the issues I found seem to be related to missing texture packs. But I personally don't use any yet so... I don't know what to do.
Here's my project: https://pasteall.org/blend/8f4ab8170c414143a22ffaa71e7362bc

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "sneak peak"? Can you upload a screenshot of the pink objects so we can better see what you mean? In Material Preview mod (key Z) I see 4 white objects because they have no material. In workspace "Texture Paint" (main tab) there is one object pink. It's ok because it has no material.

Comment: If you're talking about the render (F12, after adding a camera), indeed there are 4 pink objects. If you want to have them in a different color you need to create a material and choose a color. Materials don't require textures.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! "Sneak peak" is a feature of Verge3D.. It is different from rendering I think, but I'm unsure. Anyway, I ended up solving the issue only by appending my objects to a new empty project. I think my problem was with the fact that I deleted a light source at some point... Anyway, I didn't really "solve" my problem, but I was able to get rid of it at least ;)